# Adding Videos as Planes audio problem

Tags: video, audio

When I ADD a video (mp4 format) as a plane, I don't hear any audio from the video. Video is playing ok though. Any ideas why ?

Comment: I think I saw a timeline in the video editor for audio, does it show anything? I kind of suspect it only adds the visual part to the blender file when one adds as plane. It seems there is a Speaker object as well.

Comment: The speaker feature is for adding (importing) your own audio. I was just told by someone that this manuall importing of audio is the only way to solve the problem.